# NumericStepper flash component valyes

Tags: flash

I am trying to use numericstepper flash component (adobe flash cs6) unfortunately I can set only min/max value like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ++++++++

What I would like to have, is something like:

> -2
>   -1.75
>   -1.50
>   -1.25
>   -1.00
>   -0.75
>   -0.50
>   -0.25 0
>   +0.25
>   +0.50
>   +0.75
>   +1.00
>   +1.25
>   +1.50
>   +1.75
>   +2.00

etc, would be grateful for some help.

Comment: found a solution and corrected my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002742.html

please use numericStepperInstance.stepSize